# How to split number and digit in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please help me on the following calculation in a stored procedure.

My scenario is packing the magazine

Example:

Order = 6042 copies. 6042 have to be packed by 20 each, so I get 302 bundles and a balance of 2 copies.

If I divide 6042 / 20, result is 302.10. How can I store 302 and 2 in different columns that mean 302 is one column and 2 is another.

It is also differ the packing qty. Like some time 20 or 30 or 50 or 10
Also copies  are also differ upto  9999 copies

Currently my stored procedure is:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SOMaster_TEMP] 
SET [BSTD] = [Qty] / [STDB]

UPDATE [dbo].[SOMaster_TEMP] 
SET [BEND] = [Qty] / [STDB]
```

- `Qty` is copies  = 6042.
- `STDB` = 20 per bundle.
- `BSTD` is calculated as 302.10.
- `BEND` is also 302.10.

Comment: Can you please show us the **table structure** ? What **datatypes** are your columns?

Answer (score 0):

If those are `INT` datatypes, then you can easily use integer division and the modulo operator:

```
DECLARE @Qty INT = 6042
DECLARE @PerBundle INT = 20

SELECT 
    NumberOfBundles = @Qty / @PerBundle,
    BalanceCopies = @Qty % @PerBundle
```

This results in:

[image]